# How to detect the row of a ControlList at mouse position

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I want change the hint of the ControlList, detecting which row the mouse is over, so for example the hint could say 'Row 6'

I know that I can do this with TStringList as shown in the following example.

TStringList Example:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  Col, Row: Integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.MouseToCell(X, Y, Col, Row);
  StringGrid1.Hint := IntToStr(Col) + '   ' + IntToStr(Row);
end;
```

ControlList Example:

```
procedure TForm1.ControlList1MouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    var
   Row: Integer;
    begin
       ControlList1.  <--------Looking for something like Mouse to Row
       ControlList1.Hint := IntToStr(Row);
    end;
```

FYI, in the ControlList BeforeDraw Item AIndex is available. It would be great to get the the AIndex or Row.

```
ControlList1BeforeDrawItem(
  AIndex: Integer; ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; AState: TOwnerDrawState);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TControlList* exposes a property *HotItemIndex* for that.